# Is it a complete metric space

Tags: general-topology, analysis

How to know if these two spaces are complete or not ?

$(\mathbb{R}, d)$ where $d(x,y)=|x^3-y^3|$

$(\mathbb{R}, d')$ where $d'(x,y)= \ln(1+|x-y|)$

thank you very much

Comment: If you find my answer useful, consider upvoting and/or accepting it. Else, consider leaving a comment on how it could be improved. [Why should we accept answers](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3399)?.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $(x_n)$ be a $d$-Cauchy sequence. Then $(y_n) := (x_n^3)$ is a $|\cdot|$-Cauchy sequence, i.e. w.r.t the usual metric $d_u(x,y) := |x - y|$. But with this metric $\mathbb{R}$ is complete hence $y_n \overset{d_u}{\to} y$. Now the claim is that $x_n \overset{d}{\to} \sqrt[3]{y}$. But this is easy: Let $\varepsilon > 0$ be given. Then there exists some $N$ such that for all $n \geq N$ we have
$$
d(x_n, \sqrt[3]{y}) = |x_n^3 - (\sqrt[3]{y})^3| =|y_n - y| = d_u(y_n, y) < \varepsilon.
$$

The other one is very similar, i.e. you should try to play everything back to the metric space you know the most about: $\mathbb{R}$ with the euclidean metric.

Let $(x_n)$ be a $d'$-Cauchy sequence. For each $\varepsilon > 0$ you will have some $N$ such that for all $n,m \geq N$ 
$$
\ln(1 + |x_n - x_m|) \leq \varepsilon
$$
By the monotonicity of the exponential function you can rewrite this inequality to
$$
|x_n - x_m| \leq e^\varepsilon - 1.
$$
But since $e^\varepsilon \to 1$ for $\varepsilon \to 0$, you see that $(x_n)$ is as well a $d_u$-Cauchy sequence. Since $(\mathbb R, d_u)$ is complete there exists some $x \in \mathbb{R}$ with $x_n \overset{d_u}{\to} x$. Let $\varepsilon > 0$ be given. Then by $d_u$-convergence of the sequence $x_n$ there exists $N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that for all $n \geq N$ we have
$$
|x - x_n| \leq e^\varepsilon - 1. \tag{$\ast$}
$$
Going backwards and using the monotonicity of the logarithm, this gives that 
$$
d'(x,x_n) = \ln(1 + |x - x_n|) \leq \varepsilon.
$$

Comment: for example what i must (y_n) in the second space ?

Comment: @Vrouvrou: If you try to write it down, you will see that you won't need another sequence, i.e. (y_n) = (x_n).

Comment: i must prove that $\ln(1+|x_n-x|)\rightarrow0$ i have that $0\leq \ln(1+|x_n-x|)\leq |x_n-x|$ but how to see that $|x_n-x|\rightarrow0$

Comment: @Vrouvrou: The trick is, to prove that $|x_n - x| \to 0$ by proving that $(x_n)$ is $|\cdot|$-Cauchy and then use the continuity of the natural logarithm. See my updated post.

Comment: @Vrouvrou: Have you been able to overcome the remaining difficulties?

Comment: please when we deduce that $(x_n)$ converge in $(R,|.|)$ to x how to deduce that $(x_n)$ converge in (R,d) to the same x ?

Comment: Are you referring to the first or the second example? @Vrouvrou

Comment: The second one please

Comment: @Vrouvrou: I have updated my post.

Comment: i think that it will give $\ln(1+|x+y|)\leq \ln(1+\varepsilon)$

Comment: @Vrouvrou: Why? Just add 1 on both sides of the inequality and take logarithms on both sides.

Comment: yes that what i do !!!! $|x_n-x|<\varepsilon$ then $\ln(1+|x+y|)\leq \ln(1+\varepsilon)$

Comment: @Vrouvrou: This makes no sense. You have to use $\varepsilon' = e^\varepsilon - 1$, i.e. you have to work with equation $(\ast)$